# Trigger `git prune` automatically on `git pull`?

Tags: git

On my local copy of a company-wide repository (where I make lots of short-lived branches and `git rebase` very very often, and where many other people are also pushing short-lived branches to the `origin` I'm pulling from), I regularly have the following conversation with git.

```
(env)$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 382, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (247/247), done.
remote: Total 382 (delta 182), reused 62 (delta 62), pack-reused 73
Receiving objects: 100% (382/382), 228.63 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (232/232), completed with 15 local objects.
From github.com:anon/anony2
   aee962f..055a717  master     -> origin/master
   [...]
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
error: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
and remove .git/gc.log.
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.

Updating aee962f..055a717
Fast-forward
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
error: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
and remove .git/gc.log.
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.
 [...]
 9 files changed, 128 insertions(+), 95 deletions(-)
(env)$ git prune
Checking connectivity: 772524, done.
(env)$ rm .git/gc.log
(env)$
```

```

That is: I say `git pull`; git spews a bunch of stuff at me, helpfully including two commands I need to run; I run those commands; then I can continue with my work.

It would be awesome if git would just *run those commands for me*, instead of forcing me to cut-and-paste them. I get that this wouldn't be the default behavior of `git pull`, but it seems like the sort of thing that probably exists as an option I could add to my `.gitconfig`. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: IIUC, the only reason the automatic `git gc` isn't Doing The Right Thing already is because my `git reflog` is crazy big due to all my aggressive rebasing (and things still in the reflog don't get gc'ed but they do get prune'd). If "reducing the default retention policy for my reflog" is both possible and sufficient to fix my problem, I'd accept an answer that just described how to do that.

Comment: Why not writing a shell script for that?

Comment: @kabanus: I might accept an answer that involved writing a shell script; but it would have to DTRT when `git pull` fails, and it would have to be a drop-in replacement for `git pull` (i.e., I should be able to invoke it on the command line as `git pull`, `git pull origin`, etc., and specifically *not* as `my-git-pull.sh` or whatever, because my fingers don't know that phrase); and even then it would be a suboptimal answer because it wouldn't end up teaching me anything about how to use git. But it might win out over an answer along the lines of "This is in git 3.7.42; just upgrade!" ;)

Comment: What's the output of `git config --get extensions.preciousobjects`? (This was introduced in Git 2.7.0; it prevents `git gc` from pruning objects.)

Comment: @torek: `git config --get extensions.preciousobjects` prints nothing and returns exit code 1. `git --version` prints `git version 2.9.3`.

Comment: OK, so it's the more likely problem. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you generate loose objects fast enough to, in effect, overrun [the default `git gc` protection time of `2.weeks.ago`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html):

> `--prune=<date>`
>          Prune loose objects older than date (default is 2 weeks ago,
>    overridable by the config variable `gc.pruneExpire`). --prune=all
>    prunes loose objects regardless of their age (do not use
>    --prune=all unless you know exactly what you are doing. Unless the
>    repository is quiescent, you will lose newly created objects that
>    haven't been anchored with the refs and end up corrupting your
>    repository). --prune is on by default.

What's happening here is that `git gc` is automatically, in the background, pruning loose objects with its default mechanism, which is to run `git prune --expire=2.weeks.ago` (or whatever you have configured for `gc.pruneExpire`).  But this leaves behind enough loose objects that `git gc` thinks it has done a poor job of pruning.

Running `git prune` with no expire time (as in manual `git prune`), or with `--prune=all` in `git gc`, removes *all* loose objects.  This is only safe if no other Git command is running.  Since `git gc --auto` runs in the background, it needs a safety margin—but two weeks is too much for your usage.

If you're confident that your various Git commands will complete in just one week, or even perhaps a day, :-) you can configure `gc.pruneExpire` to `1.week.ago` or `1.day.ago` to make it prune more aggressively.  Unless you're generating a really huge number of loose objects, that will probably do the trick:

```
$ git config gc.pruneExpire 3.days.ago
```

Note that when set this way, you change only the setting for *this* repository, and override any more global setting.  Or:

```
$ git config --global gc.pruneExpire 1.week.ago
```

This sets your personal (user-global) default to one week, instead of two (but this will be overridden by the repo-specific "three days" setting, if that's set).

---

I noticed while checking all this that `extensions.preciousObjects` is not documented.  (As with all config variables, this may be spelled with arbitrary upper and lower case mixtures.)  It was added in Git 2.7.0 and lets you prevent *all* automatic pruning of objects, which you might want if you set up a shared repository.  (It's tricky to use and probably not something any casual user should ever set.)

Comment: This answer could be improved (even further!) by showing exactly how to enable `gc.pruneExpire` in the .gitconfig file. Pretty sure I should create a `[gc]` section and add `pruneExpire = 1.week.ago` to that section, but just for the record...?

Comment: It'll be hard to tell if this works (since if it works I won't notice, by definition :)), but I'm at least provisionally accepting it. Thanks!